# concate column values using new line character informix

Tags: informix

I would like to make update of column value from a table using multiple column values from another table in informix.

Here is an example:

```
            select name||'\n '||address||'\n '||place, email, phone
            into v_name,v_email,v_phone
            from users where id=v_user_id;
            update users_tab set
            naziv=v_name, telefon=v_phone, email=v_email
            where id=v_id;
```

I like \n to be written in database column as new line character, as this example:

naziv=Name Address Place
not as naziv=Name\nAddress\nPlace

Is there a way to do this in informix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the ALLOW_NEWLINE configuration parameter, or alternatively run `EXECUTE PROCEDURE IFX_ALLOW_NEWLINE('T')` in the relevant session. [There's some comments on this issue in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1615.htm?lang=en).

Note that the new line character needs to be a literal, i.e.

```
select name||'
'||address||'
'||place, email, phone
            into v_name,v_email,v_phone
            from users where id=v_user_id;
            update users_tab set
            naziv=v_name, telefon=v_phone, email=v_email
            where id=v_id;
```

... although that depends somewhat on the programming language and how the SQL is prepared/executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one table with once record when two fields contains `\n` and `\t`, for example:

create table ccr(
cr char(1),
tb char(1)
);

then load the chars from text file.
into file c:\a.txt

escape char(`\`) + [enter],escape char(`\`) + [tab],

Potgresql
copy from copy (select * from ccr) from "c:\a.txt" delimiter `','` csv HEADER quote `'"'`

Informix:
load from a.txt delimiter ',' insert into ccr

To use the chars:

select name || cr || address || cr || tb || place, email, phone
            into v_name,v_email,v_phone
            from users where id=v_user_id;
            update users_tab set
            naziv=v_name, telefon=v_phone, email=v_email
            where id=v_id;